# Semantic of startsWith on Arrays

Tags: arrays, scala, collections

I was caught off guard by this expression:

```
val words = strings.map(s => s.split(“,”)) // split CSV data
val nonHashWords = words.filter(word => word.startsWith(“#”))
```

This construction is faulty, as `words` is a `Seq[Array[String]]` instead of the intented `Seq[String]`.
I didn’t expect that Array would have a `startsWith` method, so I played a bit with it to understand its semantics. I naturally expected this to be true: `Array(“hello”, “world”).startsWith(“hello”)`

Here’s the rest of my exploration session:

```
scala> val s = Array("hello","world")
s: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)

scala> s.startsWith("hello")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> s.startsWith("h")
res1: Boolean = false

scala> val s = Array("hello","hworld")
s: Array[String] = Array(hello, hworld)

scala> s.startsWith("h")
res3: Boolean = false

scala> s.startsWith("hworld")
res4: Boolean = false

scala> s.toString
res5: String = [Ljava.lang.String;@11ed068

scala> s.startsWith("[L")
res6: Boolean = false

scala> s.startsWith("[")
res7: Boolean = false
```

What is the expected behavior of ‘array.startsWith’ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the docs:

> def startsWith[B](that: GenSeq[B]): Boolean Tests whether this mutable
>   indexed sequence starts with the given sequence.

So `array.startsWith(x)` expects `x` to be a sequence.

```
scala> val s = Array("hello","world")
scala> s.startsWith(Seq("hello"))
res8: Boolean = true
```

What happens in the question above is that the string passed as parameter is evaluated as a sequence of characters. That leads to no compiler error although in that specific case it will not yield the expected result.

This should illustrate that:

```
scala> val hello = Array('h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d')
hello: Array[Char] = Array(h, e, l, l, o,  , w, o, r, l, d)

scala> hello.startsWith("hello")
res9: Boolean = true
```